# Remove window event listener on unbind Vue directive lifecycle

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-directives

I have just come accross with an issue related to event listening in Vue directives.
I have a component which holds following code inside:

```
function setHeaderWrapperHeight() { ... }
function scrollEventHandler() { ... }

export default {
  ...
  directives: {
    fox: {
      inserted(el, binding, vnode) {
        setHeaderWrapperHeight(el);
        el.classList.add('header__unfixed');
        window.addEventListener(
          'scroll',
          scrollEventListener.bind(null, el, binding.arg)
        );
        window.addEventListener(
          'resize',
          setHeaderWrapperHeight.bind(null, el)
        );
      },
      unbind(el, binding) {
        console.log('Unbound');
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollEventListener);
        window.removeEventListener('resize', setHeaderWrapperHeight);
      }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

And this component is re-rendered everytime I change router path, I achieved this behaviour by assigning current route path to `:key` prop so whenever path changes it gets re-rendered. But the propblem is though event listeners are not being removed/destroyed causing terrible performance issues. So how do I remove event listeners?

Comment: Try removing the event listeners in the component's [destroyed](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#destroyed) lifecycle hook, rather than in from within the directive,

Comment: @DigitalDrifter Still getting the same results

Comment: @DigitalDrifter Yes I am using VueRouter, As it's been figured out the problem was more javascript specific so calling `bind()` on function created new function and therefore removeEventListener was getting wrong function reference. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `bind` on a function creates a new function. The listeners aren't being removed because the function you're passing to `removeEventListener` is not the same function you passed to `addEventListener`.

Communicating between hooks in directives is not particularly easy. The official documentation recommends using the element's `dataset`, though that seems clumsy in this case:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Directive-Hook-Arguments

You could just store the listeners on the element directly as properties so that they're available in the `unbind` hook.

The code below takes a slightly different approach. It uses an array to hold all of the elements that are currently bound to the directive. The listener on `window` is only ever registered once, no matter how many times the directive is used. If the directive isn't currently being used then that listener is removed:

```js
let foxElements = []

function onClick () {
  console.log('click triggered')

  for (const entry of foxElements) {
    clickHandler(entry.el, entry.arg)
  }
}

function clickHandler (el, arg) {
  console.log('clicked', el, arg)
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data () {
    return {
      items: [0]
    }
  },

  directives: {
    fox: {
      inserted (el, binding) {
        console.log('inserted')
        
        if (foxElements.length === 0) {
          console.log('adding window listener')
          window.addEventListener('click', onClick)
        }

        foxElements.push({
          el,
          arg: binding.arg
        })
      },

      unbind (el, binding) {
        console.log('unbind')
      
        foxElements = foxElements.filter(element => element.el !== el)
        
        if (foxElements.length === 0) {
          console.log('removing window listener')
          window.removeEventListener('click', onClick)
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="items.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000))">Add</button>
  <hr>
  <button
    v-for="(item, index) in items"
    v-fox:example
    @click="items.splice(index, 1)"
  >Remove {{ item }}</button>
</div>
```

However, all of this assumes that a directive is even the right way to go. If you can just do this at the component level then it may get a lot simpler because you have the component instance available to store things. Just remember that calling `bind` creates a new function, so you'll need to keep a reference to that function somewhere so you can pass it to `removeEventListener`.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the records, and to help whoever passes through here as there is already an accepted answer, what one could do in this case (on Vue 3 at least, not tested on Vue 2) is to use `binding.dir` (which is a reference to the directive's own object) to host the function for adding the event listener on the directive object and take it back later when there's a need to remove this listener.

One simple example (not related to the original question) for binding one focus event:

```js
export default {
  ...
  directives: {
    fox: {
      handleFocus: () => { /* a placeholder to rewrite later */ },
      mounted(el, binding) {
        binding.dir.handleFocus = () => { /* do whatever */ }
        el.addEventListener('focus', binding.dir.handleFocus);
      },
      beforeUnmount(el, binding) {
        el.removeEventListener('focus', binding.dir.handleFocus);
      }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

A practical example of what I'm doing with this, in my case, is to have a focus/blur notifier for any input or textarea tag. I made a Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/msandrini/f87eaeb438d38247ed8960e298c4a0e8) of this, it is on a project built on Vue 3 with TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution (with some help from chatgpt) for adding/removing the event listener on the window, in this case a resizing handler:

```
  .directive('resize', {
    beforeMount(el, binding, vnode) {
      const onResizeCallback = binding.value;
      window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        const width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        const height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        onResizeCallback({ width, height });
      }, { passive: true });
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle, no-param-reassign
      el._resizeListener = binding.value;
    },
    unmounted(el) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
      window.removeEventListener('resize', el._resizeListener);
    },
  })
```